# multiline textbox validation ms access

Tags: regex, validation, ms-access, textbox, vba

Hi I am pretty new to Ms Access and I could use some of your expertise to advise:

I would like to validate the text of a multiline textbox, so that the user can only enter 2 capital letters - 7 numbers - semi-colon - new line.  As an example, the textbox would look like this (but with each entry on a new line, since I have it so that enter makes a new line in the textbox

```
AB1234567; SE0001848; SE0019591; RE0010599; etc.
```

I think this is too complex for a validation rule.  I also think it's too complex for an input mask.  I started looking into RegEx to validate the text but I am hungup on how to have the code evaluate each new line in the multiline textbox so that the entire textbox is evaluated.  Do i need to do a loop of some sort?

Ultimately, I would like the user to get a message box when they enter their text incorrectly that blocks the entry from being added to the record and also explains to the user that they need to modify their entry so that it is valid.

Answer (score 2):

I think your idea of RegEx is the easiest but you'll need to add a reference (see code).

This should do what you want (just replace Text14 with your text control)

Note - I removed the CANCEL=TRUE because that wipes out the users data. The best route woul dbe to make sure the text box is UNBOUND - then if valid you would update the actual field if the RegExp is validated for all lines

```vb
Private Sub Text14_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    ' Requires reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"
    ' Under Tools | References
    ' Add Reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"

    ' 2 Capital Letters followed by 7 digits and ";'
    Const VALID_LINE    As String = "[A-Z]{2}[\d]{7};"

    Dim regEx As New RegExp

    Dim strData     As String  ' Read in textbox
    Dim varLines    As Variant ' Use this to hold lines of text

    Dim intNumLines As Integer
    Dim intLine     As Integer
    Dim strLine     As String

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .Multiline = False
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = VALID_LINE
    End With

    ' Replace Text14 with your text box control name
    strData = Text14.Value ' Get Data from Text box

    ' Split data into lines using Carriage Return Line Feed delimiters
    varLines = Split(strData, vbCrLf)

    ' Go thru all lines to check for data issue
    intNumLines = UBound(varLines)
    For intLine = 0 To intNumLines
        strLine = varLines(intLine)
        If Not regEx.Test(strLine) Then
            MsgBox "Problem with Line #" & (intLine + 1)
            ' Cancel - if you want to wipe out data
            ' Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox "Data Looks Good: All " & intNumLines & " Lines"

End Sub
```

Comment: If the text box should be bound, the code can also go into the `Form_BeforeUpdate` event procedure (then with `Cancel = True`), so the record can't be saved if the text isn't valid.

Comment: Going to try this and report back.  Getting pumped that it might actually work!

Comment: You're welcome. You had a great start with a well thought our question with alternatives